# All Eclipse C++ Programs Fail to Run, Hangs on "Launching Delegate"

Tags: eclipse, compilation, mingw

A few days ago, Eclipse for C/C++ (Helios) stopped running my programs. They can be compiled with MinGW without displaying any errors. However, when the programs are run, Eclipse always get stuck at "Launching Delegate" at 70%. No matter how long I wait, the program never starts. The same happens when I try to run the program from the command line; no matter how simple the program, the command line just does nothing, as if it is waiting for the program to start.

I believed that this was just an issue with my Eclipse workspace, so I created a new workspace and tested a Hello World application, but it failed too. I reverted to an older version of Eclipse (Indigo), and a 32-bit version, but these had the same error. I even installed a different IDE, Netbeans, but it too never runs any programs. So, clearly, it's not just Eclipse. I tried reinstalling MinGW, but this also didn't help.

I have tried everything I can possibly think of. I could only find one other person with the same problem online, and theirs was never answered. Can anyone help me out with this strange issue?

Comment: It failed to be ran by the command line too? This is weird, maybe it's your program. Test a hello world in the command line to see if you can get any results.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Always stuck at 70%. However, it turned out that somehow it can be fixed by disabling my anti-virus program, when I want to run a C/C++ program. Which I find to be quite strange.

I hope it helps.